# Why can't I push to my repository?

Tags: git

I am setting up a git repository on my home network with the URL 10.0.0.250. I can ssh to the server machine very well. Also, on my client, I can git add, commit. But when i do "git push origin master", it got stuck there, without any message indicating what's going on.

```
abigail@abilina:~/my-project$ git push origin master
git@10.0.0.250's password: 
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 216 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

What's the possible problem?

**EDIT:** My repository is empty, newly created, as shown below.

```
abigail@abilina:~/my-project$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Maybe Your repository already pushed please double check.

Comment: Not an answer, but what happens when you `git fetch`?  Maybe you will get a more useful error message in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, nothing happens, no message, when run 'git fetch'.

Comment: @AshishDetroja. No first time to test. A new repository

Comment: Well did you create a new repository on your home computer?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's an empty repository. see my editing.

Comment: Any comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Git didn't provide errors, because it successfully pushed your commits to remote repository. You can ensure this by connecting to server via SSH, switching to repo directory and invoking `git log master`. You should see your commits in the log list.

However, you didn't set tracking between your local branch `master` and remote branch `origin/master`, that's why `git status` doesn't show you whether branch is up-to-date or ahead of remote branch by several commits. You should do `git push origin master --set-upstream` (or `-u`) once to fix it.